# how to add a certain amount to the woocommerce regular price?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

My webshop is based in Spain and I am trying to add 20% (my profit) for every product that I have in my shop (regardless the customer's location). I tried to work with the TAX feature but the regular price gets displayed and my tax options are simply ignored. I tried this code `<p class="price-incvat"> <?php echo woocommerce_price($product->get_price_including_tax()); ?> Inc VAT</p>` but the regular price is displayed again. This is how my tax TAB looks. [image]
[image]